# Enabling extra spacing at the top of page for a given style

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

In a Word 2013 document, I have a “Document title” style which has a 170 pt spacing before. When used at the first page of the document *or* at the first page of a *section* (inserting a *section break* before), the spacing is applied correctly. However, if I use the same style in the middle of a document in order to separate parts of a document (e.g. a “Part A — Blah blah” kind of title), the spacing is **not applied**.

In previous Word versions, there was a setting to actually *suppress* adding space before for a paragraph at the very top of the page. However, I'm looking for the exact opposite setting.

How do I enable rendering the 'spacing before' for a paragraph placed at the top of a page in the middle of a document without a *section break* before?

Comment: Use a section break. That's the whole point of using a section break. If you don't want to use a section break then just use a new style and format the paragraph appropriately.

Comment: Alternatively, you could simply add a bit of space to the page header or create a separate spacer style that you apply to an empty paragraph.  Any of these approaches should work if the document needs to switch between Word versions (or platforms).

Comment: @DavidPostill The issue is such formatting won't work. Word just ignores 'spacing before' in that case.

Comment: @LanceLeonard A spacer style is what I considered. However, it's a bit annoying. Currently I stick with section breaks, although it has similar disadvantages as the spacer style. Making a bigger top margin is not a usable solution. IMHO having level 1 headings with a space above is a very frequent typographical requirement, so I'm looking for a *native* solution without workarounds.